# Template 10 :Hamburger Panel color not changing

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows, windows-10-universal, template10

I am creating  a uwp app and when i set my xaml code to this

```
<Controls:HamburgerMenu x:Name="MyHamburgerMenu"  HamburgerBackground="#FFD13438"
                HamburgerForeground="White"
                NavAreaBackground="# FF2B2B2B"
                NavButtonBackground="#FFD13438"
                SecondarySeparator="White"
                NavButtonForeground="White" 
                LostFocus="MyHamburgerMenu_LostFocus"
                  DisplayMode="CompactOverlay"


                        >
```

Its not changing the color of the Hamburger Panel I have tried all colors.Its still shows the default colors only.
Also even when i change the display mode it still pushes the Title Page.
I dont whats causing the issue.My Template 10 version is  v1.1.10.

[The issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FleMa.png)

Comment: What is this HamburgerMenu control? Did you make it yourself?

Comment: No its a control already in template 10 and in documentation of that its said that you can change the color just like i typed. @GlenThomas https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki/Docs-%7C-Controls#hamburgermenu

Comment: I got it to work using OPs code (without space after #). My issue was that the style.xaml was not being seen. But after I removed AccentColor in TargetType="controls:HamburgerMenu the other colors came through. It appears that AccentColor was overriding.

Answer (score 1):

To set the background color of the hamburger panel, you have to use the NavAreaBackground dependency property as you did. It should work fine. The problem is the space character between '#' and the hexadecimal value 'FF2B2B2B' in your code. Just remove the space character and it will work : NavAreaBackground="#FF2B2B2B"

Comment: I have done that and its still not working i think its because of the issue  of  #860 the template 10 .                                                                                                https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/860

Comment: Definitely the hamburger panel color could not be set properly with the space character inserted as you did in your original code "# FF2B2B2B". If the problem still persists, then the root cause might not come from the basic xaml code you provide. I suggest you to post the full detail of the xaml page. Did you define elsewhere some custom style for the HamburgerMenu control ? Furthermore I don't understand why you suspect the issue #860 which relates to behavior interactivity SDK assembly reference.

Answer (score 1):

In your Shell.xaml.cs file just comment this line `HamburgerMenu.RefreshStyles(_settings.AppTheme, true);`

It should work.